# Does Raspbian run any GUI by default? Can I uninstall some of its components?

Tags: headless

I have downloaded default Raspbian distribution and now I'm already installing stuff on the Pi. Because I have no HDMI cable, nor USB keyboard I do everything via SSH. Successfully so far.

I also have no suitable SD card, so I use an old, tiny miniSD card and a reduction. Due to a limited size of that card, I wonder where could I save up some space.

The Debian has 2 (!) gigabytes of data. This is quite a lot for what is currently capable of, so  believe there are tons of images or some sort of stuff (just don't tell me these are 2 GB of compiled code).

So I'm wondering about how to:

1. Turn the GUI off if it's running on startup, and do not start it automatically
2. Uninstall useless stuff related to the GUI (eg. browser and so on, but **not** the GUI itself, in case I ever needed it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Debian has 2 (!) gigabytes of data. This is quite a lot for what is currently capable of, so believe there are tons of images or some sort of stuff (just don't tell me these are 2 GB of compiled code).

Yes, 95%+ of that is just executables ("compiled code").  2 GB is in fact significantly *below* the average for a PC OS with GUI -- half the size of mainstream linux distros, which are still 1/2 to 1/4 the size of major commercial OS's.

> Turn the GUI of if it's running on startup, and do not start it automatically

The last raspbian image I checked it's not on automatically, which is a bit different from normal debian, I think.  It's enabled in runlevels 3-5, but the default is 2.

> Uninstall useless stuff related to the GUI (eg. browser and so on, but not the GUI itself, in case I ever needed it)

You won't save much space that way, a few MB here and there.

But: glancing through output from `du -h` on the raspbian 2013-12-20 image, I notice a whopping 422 MB in `/opt/WolframEngine`.  Google that yourself to find out what it is; in any case, it's not necessary. I don't know when or why raspbian added this to the base image (I doubt very much it is in the normal debian, or any other normal distro base...go figure).

Since `apt-cache search wolfram` only names one package, that's probably what you want to pull.  Try:

```
apt-get remove wolfram-engine
```

Then check to make sure the directory in `/opt` is gone.  That should free up enough space until you get a 4+ GB card.  `apt-get install wolfram-engine` on raspbian sans the package wants "588 MB of additional disk space", part of which is oracle java 7.  Meaning you likely also have oracle 7 installed and probably don't need that either (if you want an oracle java, use the 8 version which is compiled for the hard float pi).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much - this surely will be enough until I get some card for PI.

Comment: Removing wolfram-engine and oracle-java7 freed up 554Mb -- a big chunk of my 4Gb card